# How to add translation fields in django-taggit?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, django-modeltranslation

I am working  on multi language web-site. In my apps I am using django modeltranslation to set values on different languages from admin. So how can I add modeltranslation into [django-taggit](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to have a tag on different languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I came around, when I was looking for the same issue:

```
#models.py
@register_snippet
class BlogTag(TagBase):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "tags"

    #this is for editing in wagtail. For django not needed
    panels =  [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
    ]

class BlogPageTag(ItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        BlogTag, related_name="tagged_blogs", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    content_object = ParentalKey('BlogPage', related_name='post_tags')

from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager

class BlogPage(Page):
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
```

And in the translation.py:

```
#translation.py
from .models import BlogPage,BlogTag
from django_modeltranslation.translation import TranslationOptions,register


@register(BlogPage)
class BlogPageTR(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
       'intro','body',
    )

@register(BlogTag)
class BlogTagTR(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
      'name',
    )
```

Comment: Worked well in Wagtail as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to subclass TagBase and add your own translatable fields instead.